# I can't seem to find a formula for the partial sums of this infinite series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, pointwise-convergence

I'm working on a problem set for my partial differential equations class. We are studying convergence of Fourier Series. One of the questions is asking me to compute whether
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n}$$
is pointwise convergent on the interval $-1<x<1$. The problem gives the hint that the partial sums can be explicitly computed. For some reason, my brain is emitting noxious levels of fart, and I can't find a formula for the partial sums of the series.

I have, however, managed to evaluate the series on the interval $-1<x<1$ without using partial sums by taking advantage of the fact that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n}=1-x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n}$$
and through rearranging, I found that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n}=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$

If anyone would be willing to point me in the right direction to finding an explicit formula for the partial sums, that would be incredibly helpful. It has been a few years since I have taken Calculus II and I've clearly forgotten some things.

Comment: $~1 + y + y^2 + \cdots + y^n = \dfrac{1 - y^{n+1}}{1-y}.~$  Simply **plug in** $~y = [(-1)\times x^2].~$

Comment: I am struggling to figure out what your question is.

Comment: @uggupuggu Sorry, I just now realized I included a bunch of unnecessary information in my question. I'm just trying to find a formula for the partial sums of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n}$